# WPF MVVM Capture Global Exception Handler to Context

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, prism

C#, WPF, .NET Framework 4.5, EntityFramework, Prism

All my Models were auto generated by adding an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" and selecting "Code First from Database." No changes to the Models, everything is handled in the ViewModels. Then I created IModel classes that contain:

```
ICollection<Model> GetEntities();
void CreateEntity(Model entity);
```

Then I created service classes, like ModelService, that flesh out the above methods and implement IDisposable. Then the ViewModels use all the above as so:

```
public IModel modelContext;
public ICollection<Model> Models; { get; private set;}

public ViewModel(IModel modelContext)
{
    Models = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    this.modelContext = modelContext;
}
```

All the above works great... except in App.xaml.cs... and here's what I'm going for. I implemented Global Exception Handling by adding the following to App.xaml (not cs):

```
<Application DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException">
```

Then, here is all of the App.xaml.cs. I have a SQL table and model called ErrorLog where I want to catch and save all errors:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly string user = Environment.UserName;
    private IErrorLog errorLogContext;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {            
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();
    }

    private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var errorLog = new ErrorLog
        {
            Message = e.Exception.Message,
            DateTime = DateTime.Now,
            User = user,
            Location = "Global Exception Handler"
        };

        errorLogContext.CreateEntity(errorLog);            

        MessageBox.Show("An unhandled exception just occurred: " + e.Exception.Message, "App Title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        e.Handled = true;

    }
}
```

The problem is the context needs to be initialized like it does in ViewModels, as is errorLogContext whines in the warnings that it will always be null. I try to add it to the constructor of any of the above methods or create public App(IErrorLog errorLogContext) and I get that there's no override method warnings... So... where should I put the setup that I'm missing so that I can save Exceptions to my database?

Comment: Can you specify how you want to initialize your errorLogContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have to handle the exceptions in the apps code behind?

You can do that in your main window viewmodel. I am doing this and it is working fine.

```
if (Application.Current != null)
            {
                Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += (s, a) =>
                {
                    Reporter.AddLog(a.Exception);

                    DisplayAppropriateNotification(a);

                    a.Handled = true;
                };
            }
```

This is what I am doing in the constructor of my MainWindowViewmodel.

I guess you will have the context created in the viewmodel.

Comment: When I found an end user guinea pig, they were getting immediate errors crashing and killing the app. So I was just thinking i had to have the Global Handler as close to app startup as I could get it. If it will work in MainWindowViewModel though, then that makes this super easy. I'm going to try what you're doing when I get to the office.

Comment: Perfect! I created the IErrorLog context in the MainWindowViewModel, changed the constructor to "public MainWindowViewModel(IErrorLog errorLogContext)", stuck in a line for this.errorLogContext = errorLogContext, used your code but switched the Reporter for making an entity and switched DisplayAppropriateNotification with MessageBox.Show. The only extra thing I had to do was go into Bootstrapper and add Container.RegisterType<IErrorLog, ErrorLogService>();